# Is there a way to use CSS column combinator in Pandas DataFrame Styling?

Tags: python, css, pandas-styles

I am using the Pandas DataFrame styler and want to make every other column (based on the first level of a multi index rather than hard code) have a gray background. I know that with CSS you can use the column combinator to say something like

```
Th:nth-child(2n) || td
```

but it doesn't seem to be compatible with pandas styling.

In my DataFrame I have level 0 of a multi index as months and then level 1 as some other columns. The end goal is to have every other month be highlighted in some way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas does not create column groups in HTML, and the technology is experimental in HTML anyway, so this won't work.

You are better off doing something like:

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(2,10))
    style = [{"selector": "td", "props": "background-color: grey; color: white;"}]
    df.style.set_table_styles({
        col: style for col in df.columns[::2]
    })
```

[image]

You will have to be a little more creative to structure the dict-comprehension according to your multiindex columns.